# Android:How to save application Data to phone memory in file and then retrieve it back?

Tags: android, file-management

I am new to android and am trying to develop some basic SMS application. Now, I have two fields one for phone number and other for message, I would like to store these fields in a file and when a user hits the load button I want it to pop back in the respected fields.
I tried using

```
fos.write (msg.getBytes());(fos = fileoutputstream),
```

but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I have two fields one for phone number and other for message, I would like to store these fields in a file and when a user hits the load button I want it to pop back in the respected fields.

You should use [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it would be worthwhile for you to store it in a datastore-- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html for more info.

It might also be helpful to walk through the Notepad tutorial: 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html